# Android: Not a file URI: while downloading .apk file

Tags: java, android

I want to download .apk file and install it. When I'm not using FileProvider, everything is going well, but when I create uri from file using FileProvider, I've got IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: content://pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.provider/external_storage_root/klasa1a.apk on line

```
final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
```

I tried everything from stackoverflow but nothing helped. Here is my code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "klasa1a.apk");
final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

        //Delete update file if exists
        //File file = new File(destination);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        //get url of app on server
        String url = "http://rasztabiga.ct8.pl/klasa1a.apk";

        //set downloadmanager
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDescription("Downloading new version");
        request.setTitle(MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name));

        //set destination
        request.setDestinationUri(uri);

        // get download service and enqueue file
        final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

        //set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                install.setDataAndType(uri,
                        manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
                startActivity(install);

                unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            }
        };
        //register receiver for when .apk download is compete
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ACTION_VIEW` and `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` only support the `content` scheme as of Android 7.0. Prior to that, you have no choice but to use `file`. So, change:

```
final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
```

to:

```
final Uri uri = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N) ?
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file) :
    Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working on 7.1. It throws  the same: Not a file URI: content://pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.provider/external_storage_root/klasa1a.apk

Comment: @BartłomiejRasztabiga: It is working for me on a Nexus 9 running 7.1.1. What device are you testing on?

Comment: Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro, Android 7.1.1

Comment: @BartłomiejRasztabiga: Then that's a problem with that device. Stock Android's installer handles `content` now, [in part because I filed an issue about it 8 months ago](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205827). You will need to disable the `FileUriExposedException` using `StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());`. Then, switch to `Uri.fromFile()` for all Android versions, at least for a few years.

Comment: I ran this on sdk25 emulator and it still throws the same exception.

Comment: @BartłomiejRasztabiga: It is working for me on a 7.1.1 emulator. Copy some APK up to the root of external storage of your emulator, naming it `test.apk`. Then, download https://commonsware.com/misc/APKInstallerN.zip, unZIP it, build it, and run it. Click the bottom button. That will use `FileProvider` to install your `test.apk`. This is working for me on the emulator and the Nexus 9.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in DownloadManager. It cannot parse uri's as "content://", only as "file://" so since sdk24, we cannot use it. Using common IOStreams and HttpURLConnection everything works fine. Thanks to @CommonsWare for showing me his project. 
That's how it looks like now:

```
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "klasa1a.apk");
        final Uri uri = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) ?
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file) :
                Uri.fromFile(file);

        //Delete update file if exists
        //File file = new File(destination);
        if (file.exists())
            //file.delete() - test this, I think sometimes it doesnt work
            file.delete();

        //get url of app on server
        String url = "http://rasztabiga.ct8.pl/klasa1a.apk";

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL sUrl = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) sUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }

        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
                .setData(uri)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(install);

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that still want to use `DownloadManager` and find that the answer by CommonsWare doesn't solve the problem, you need to include an exception for APK file

```
final Uri uri = (!file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".apk") && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N) ?
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file) :
    Uri.fromFile(file);
request.setDestinationUri(uri);
```

Which is a shorter version of

```
if (!file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".apk") && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    request.setDestinationUri(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", download));
} else {
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
}
```

that may be easier to follow.

The short answer is that apk files should be handled with `Uri.fromFile`, but this does not have to come at the cost of changing the entire process.

If you want to be thorough, though, you can also catch the `IllegalArgumentException` for `Not a file URI` and use that to attempt `Uri.fromFile`